# Xamarin Forms - Draw polyline for WinPhone 8.1 part

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, maps, xamarin.forms

I cannot find the way to draw a line (polyline) with my CustomMapRenderer.cs..

```
var polyline = new MapPolyline();
polyline.StrokeColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0);
polyline.StrokeThickness = 5;
polyline.Path = new Geopath(coordinates);
nativeMap.MapElements.Add(polyline);
```

**An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in CaptainSam.WinPhone.ni.EXE but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))**

The exception comes from `polyline.Path = new Geopath(coordinates);`

It's [Highlight a Route on a Map](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/maps/map-overlay/polyline/#Creating_the_Custom_Renderer_on_the_Universal_Windows_Platform) of Microsoft tutorial, so what's happens?

*I know they says it's an example for UWP, but I also tried and it also throws the same exception...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I found why it didn't works...

If you're doing like me, if you do a `HttpRequest` to something as *Google Direction API*, then the result will comes after the first passage in the `OnElementChanged()`.

Because `formsMap.RouteCoordinates` isn't `null` but **empty**, the `Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))` is thrown..

**This is the good** `CustomMapRenderer` **for PolyLine** use

```
using PROJECT;
using PROJECT.UWP;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.UWP;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace PROJECT.UWP
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        MapControl nativeMap;
        CustomMap formsMap;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                nativeMap = Control as MapControl;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                nativeMap = Control as MapControl;
                UpdatePolyLine();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (this.Element == null || this.Control == null)
                return;

            if (e.PropertyName == CustomMap.RouteCoordinatesProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdatePolyLine();
            }
        }

        private void UpdatePolyLine()
        {
            if (formsMap != null && formsMap.RouteCoordinates.Count > 0)
            {
                List<BasicGeoposition> coordinates = new List<BasicGeoposition>();

                foreach (var position in formsMap.RouteCoordinates)
                {
                    coordinates.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = position.Latitude, Longitude = position.Longitude });
                }

                Geopath path = new Geopath(coordinates);
                MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
                polyline.StrokeColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0);
                polyline.StrokeThickness = 5;
                polyline.Path = path;
                nativeMap.MapElements.Add(polyline);
            }
        }
    }
}
```